# If $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ can we derive that the functions $f_n$ are bounded by an integrable function?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f_n,f$ be positive functions such that $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ and $f_n\in L^p(\Omega)\,\,\forall\,1\leq p<\infty.$  If $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ can we derive that the functions $f_n$ are bounded by an integrable function?  I was thinking about writing $$f_n\leq |\,f_n-f\,|+f.$$ I would appreciate any idea. thank you.

Comment: Hint: use $f_n(x) = c_n\mathbf 1_{[0,1/n]}(x)$ for a well-chosen constant $c_n$.

Comment: No. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131440/where-dct-does-not-hold-but-vitali-convergence-theorem-does).